# How to initialize memory at UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Tags: swift

I am allocating memory using UnsafeMutableRawPointer:

```
let p = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: 1000, alignedTo: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)

// do stuff

p.deallocate(bytes: 1000, alignedTo: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)
```

After I allocate, I would like to initialize the memory, ie write 0x00 to all 1000 bytes that I just allocated. Despite googling, I just can't see how to do it.

The "do stuff" is a call to a C library, which writes some bytes to the pointer; my_c_func(p)

Unfortunately, the C function would like all the bytes to be NULL. All I have is a static library, I can't change the C code.

Comment: Please elaborate what you are going to accomplish. In Swift 3+ there are many APIs which do the memory management for you for example `[UInt8](repeating: 0x0, count: 1000)`

Comment: I will amend the question.

Comment: What about `p.initializeMemory(...)` ?

Comment: Thanks guys, let me try that. I don't know Swift very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`initializeMemory(as:from:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2427765-initializememory):

> Initializes the memory referenced by this pointer with the values starting at the given pointer, binds the memory to the values’ type, and returns a typed pointer to the initialized memory.

Example (Swift 4.2):

```
let p = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 1000, alignment: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)
p.initializeMemory(as: UInt8.self, repeating: 0, count: 1000)

// Do stuff ...

p.deallocate()
```

The `initializeMemory()` method returns a *typed pointer* in case you 
need that, so you could also write

```
let uint8ptr = p.initializeMemory(as: UInt8.self, repeating: 0, count: 1000)
// UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
```

Comment: see for me, that's saying "Extra argument 'count' in call"

Comment: @PeterPrographo: That code compiles with Xcode 10 (Swift 4.2). Which version are you using?

Comment: @PeterPrographo: Then it is `p.initializeMemory(as: UInt8.self, at: 0, count: 1000, to: 0)`